# Custom EditorPart in sharepoint 2010 sandbox solution

Tags: sandbox-solution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom EditorPart in SharePoint sandboxed solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47654/custom-editorpart-in-sharepoint-sandboxed-solution)

Can anyone provide me help links or code samples describing how to create custom EditorPart for sharepoint.  am working with sandboxed visual webpart.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look here:

http://spdailytips.blogspot.in/2012/03/create-custom-editorpart-for-sandbox.html

Comment: I have created the application according to above link. But due to some reason em not able to see any controls in tool pane. Please check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835671/custom-editorpart-in-sharepoint-2010-sandbox-solution

Comment: Further I have found that the editor part works with non visual webpart. But when I work with sandboxed visual webpart then the webpart code is not executed...any idea?